# Injecting a service into a AutoMapper Mapping Profile

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, mapping, automapper

I have the following setup and its working fine

**Startup.cs**

```
public static IServiceCollection AddServices(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    serviceCollection.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
}
```

**MappingProfile class**

```cs
public class MyDtoMappingProfile: Profile
{
    public MyDtoMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<MyDtoMappingSource<MyContentType>, MyDestinationObject>()
            .ForMember(d => d.BatchFeedDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => DateTime.UtcNow));
    }
}
```

But I would like to do the following by inject the following service in the mapping profile class

**Startup.cs**

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddServices(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    serviceCollection.AddAutoMapper(builder => {
        builder.AddProfile(new MyDtoMappingProfile(serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<ILookupCodeMapper>()));
    });
}
```

**MappingProfile**

```cs
public class MyDtoMappingProfile: Profile
{
    private readonly ILookupCodeMapper lookupCodeMapper;

    public MyDtoMappingProfile(ILookupCodeMapper lookupCodeMapper)
    {
        this.lookupCodeMapper = lookupCodeMapper;

        CreateMap<MyDtoMappingSource<MyContentType>, MyDestinationObject>()
            .ForMember(d => d.BatchFeedDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => DateTime.UtcNow))
            .ForMember(d => d.Strand, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => lookupCodeMapper.Code(s.StringValue)));
    }
}
```

But when i do the above im getting this error,

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
```

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/issues/141#issuecomment-1079914176